# Using URI with Android MediaPlayer returns "path is null" and NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, path, uri

I am trying to set a button inside a `RecyclerView` Adapter that play media files that have their `URI` stored in a database.  I get the URI correctly as the log shows, however, the app crashes and `MediaPlayer` does not work. Here is the `AudioAdapter` Code:

```
public class AdapterAudio extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAudio.AudioViewHolder> {

    public static Context cxt;
    private ArrayList<Audio_Model> audioData = new ArrayList<>();

    // constructor
    public AdapterAudio(ArrayList<Audio_Model> audioData) {
        this.audioData = audioData;
    }

    @Override
    public AudioViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.audio_item, parent, false);
        AudioViewHolder holder = new AudioViewHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AudioViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        Audio_Model item = audioData.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(item.getAudio_title());
        holder.performer.setText(item.getAudio_content());
    }
}
```

PLAY AUDIO BUTTON

```
holder.playAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            pauseMusic();
        } else {
            playMusic();
        }
    }

    public void playMusic() {
        Audio_Model details = audioData.get(position);
        String source = details.getAudio_source();

        Uri audioUri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(source));

        Log.v("Audio source is: ", String.valueOf(audioUri));

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(cxt, audioUri);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pauseMusic() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();

        }
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {

        if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
});
```

Recycler View Methods

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return audioData.size();
}

public class AudioViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final Context context;
    public TextView title;
    private Audio_Model myAudio;
    private int mId;
    private TextView performer;
    private Button playAudio;

    public AzkaryViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        context = itemView.getContext();
        CardView cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_item_play);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_item_title_textViewId);
        performer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_item_performer_textViewId);
        playAudio = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_play);
        playAudio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_pause);
    }
}
```

The Log I am getting with the error message is Below:

```
10-19 20:29:37.698 9693-9693/com.myapp.audioplayer V/MediaPlayer: isPlaying: no active player
10-19 20:29:37.698 9693-9693/com.myapp.audioplayer V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 0
10-19 20:29:37.698 9693-9693/com.myapp.audioplayer V/Audio source is:: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A17
10-19 20:29:37.698 9693-9693/com.myapp.audioplayer V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_setup
10-19 20:29:37.698 9693-9693/com.myapp.audioplayer V/MediaPlayer: constructor
10-19 20:29:37.698 9693-9693/com.myapp.audioplayer V/MediaPlayer: setListener
10-19 20:29:37.698 9693-9693/com.myapp.audioplayer V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setAudioStreamType: 3
10-19 20:29:37.698 9693-9693/com.myapp.audioplayer V/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
10-19 20:29:37.698 9693-9693/com.myapp.audioplayer I/MediaPlayer: path is null
10-19 20:29:37.698 9693-9693/com.myapp.audioplayer W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 20:29:37.698 9693-9693/com.myapp.audioplayer W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1031)
10-19 20:29:37.698 9693-9693/com.myapp.audioplayer W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:986)
10-19 20:29:37.698 9693-9693/com.myapp.audioplayer W/System.err:     at audio.AdapterAudio$1.playMusic(AdapterAudio.java:151)
```

I appreciate your help in telling me what is wrong in my code that makes MediaPlayer does not work with URI.

Answer (score -1):

From what i'm seeing from the log

source is ::content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A17*

The URI returned from the database doesn't seem to be valid

You should verify it again my friend

Comment: Please explain why it is not valid.  This URI is provided directly by Android as the user select the audio file from the device storage and add it to the database as a text field.